# Will spread operator causing eager resoving?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

There a two problems:

1. Why Foo1 is not working, while Bar1/2/3 is OK? Is this by design?
2. Why Foo2 is working?

I have read all ts documents of conditional type, even the release note, nothing helps

```
type Foo1<T> = T   extends ''   ? [...Foo1<T>]   : never
// ERROR!
// Type instantiation is excessively deep and possibly infinite.

// Why this line not having the same problem?
type Foo2<T> = [T] extends [''] ? [...Foo2<T>]   : never

// Other working cases, seems like spread operator is causing eager resolving?
type Bar1<T> = T   extends ''   ? Bar1<T>        : never
type Bar2<T> = T   extends ''   ? [Bar2<T>]      : never
type Bar3<T> = T   extends ''   ? { a: Bar3<T> } : never
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAYg9nAjAHgCoD4oF4qqviAD2AgDsATAZygHIb8oB+KAbQDoP4k10BdBgFxRSEAG4QATgCgA9DKgBRAEpKA8koCEs+anDQAlqUrAAhqWD6TFuKSj7qRAMYRKlfeIA2IKOQgQwUGbkUGBwrvoARl52pABmhvokbFLaUADqABbewBn2UB6G0KRwwFAZJqKGAOZQOdCUJgC20GAScFEQjYxSoJCwCABMPNisqPxEJBTULHT8zOycgzz8+EIi4tI9elAAQiYSKBgjeATEZFS09PjMewfDDA9rYpJbfbdDRzgnUBPn1HQMebvZYPVbCZ7SXrQW4AZmGXwYvyml0BUAA3oEhLDhgBfKBPDZAA)

---

More Details:

My demo is a simplified version to make question clearer, calling to these generic types will cause infinite deep instantiation. If you need a more reasonable demo, try solving the [Type-Challenge 3376](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/03376-medium-inordertraversal/README.md).

Some solutions of it are using this `[T] extends [TreeNode] ? ... : ...` technique, like [this one](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/15193).

I understand it could prevent conditional type being distributive, but in cases Bar1/2/3, the conditional is distributive too, why it doesn't cause any trouble?

Compare `Foo1` and `Bar2`, it seems only the `...` spread operator is a special case, which is resolving eagerly. Looks inconsistent to me. Is there any documentation of this behavior?

I'm reading source code to trying to find answer, to be honest, it's "a little bit" difficult for me to understand. will share what I found here (if I could find anything eventually. )

Comment: `[T]` prevents the conditional type from being distributive.

Comment: Why do you care about the answer to this?  Clearly both `Foo1<T>` and `Foo2<T>` (and `Bar1<T>`) are ultimately illegally circular; if you ever try to use `Foo2<"">` you will get a warning there.  Does it matter *where* the compiler catches the circularity?  What is the use case?  I'd be more inclined to track down what's going on if I felt that there was some important use case at stake.

Comment: @jcalz Sorry I didn't give the context, these cases are simplified to make question clearer. I crash into this problem when doing [type-challenge 3376](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/blob/main/questions/03376-medium-inordertraversal/README.md), some solution like [this one](https://github.com/type-challenges/type-challenges/issues/15193) is using this technique, I understand it prevents being distributive, but it only solves the "union too complicate to represent" problem, why does it stop eager resolving too? And why spreading cause `Foo1<T>` to resolving eagerly at first?

Comment: I don't know that I can find anything more authoritative than [comments like this](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49263#issuecomment-1144061766) pointing to the difficulty telling the difference between "safe" and "dangerous" circular types.  I doubt that's worth writing up as an answer.